# How to sum row elements in extra column and find out data where some of field is > than x?

Tags: sqlite, python-3.7

```
SELECT *FROM 'product'
```

| row_id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 300 |
| 4 | 400 |

I would like to select x product, which sum of quantity is > than 100.

This is my expected output:

| row_id | quantity | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 200 | 300 |
| 3 | 300 | 600 |
| 4 | 400 | 1000 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY rowid) total
  FROM product
)
WHERE total > 100
```

Foe versions of SQLite that do not support window functions use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT p.*, (SELECT SUM(pp.quantity) FROM product pp WHERE pp.rowid <= p.rowid) total
  FROM product p
)
WHERE total > 100
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4a5455203600c52f213d8d5884ac5197).